# Why is particle system hair expanding the vertex group that controls the density for no reason?

Tags: hair

Subdivide the default cube to have some more faces. Assign the top faces to a vertex group. create a particle system using this vertex group in the
"particle systems->vertex groups->density"
option. The resulting hair is on more faces than just the vertex group.
WHY?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying hair density with a vertex group.  But hair isn't emitted from vertices; its emitted from faces.  To measure the density, the vertex groups you've specified are interpolated across the faces.  Let's consider this point on your mesh:

[image]

Indicated by the circle selector.  What is the density there?  It is being interpolated from the top most vertex (assigned to the density group) and the bottommost vertex (not assigned.)  Which is, 1 and 0.  So the density is not zero.

If you don't want hair emitted from a face, period, then that face has to be interpolating between 0 and 0 density.  So none of the vertices making up that face can have any weight on that vertex group.

Comment: that seems to make sense. maybe they could add a checkbox "disregard density<1" or soemthing, that would help a lot i think

Comment: @sinwar Well I think most people are using GN for the hair these days-- I certainly am.  There, it's easier to be very specific about exactly what you want.  Perhaps easier isn't the right word: you *get* to be specific, but there's work involved.  For particle hair like you have, you could consider ripping edges if you want vertex groups that don't interpolate onto neighbors, that act like face-corner groups instead.

Answer (score 0):

Almost appears to be a bug.   But, if you assign vertices that are "one short" of the top edges,

[image]

it will look as you desire.

[image]

I would be tempted to report this as a bug (Help >> Report Bug).

[image]

The same symptom exists in version 3.6.